# TCPDF: Specific text size and custom text height

Tags: tcpdf

I have a question and need some help please.

I have a requirement to show some text in size 9 and height 3mm.

How would this be possible in TCPDF?

Do i need to just increase the font size?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3mm is equivalent to 8.5pt, so yeah, 9pt font size should get you pretty close.